# Query All Opportunities With the Same Owner ID

Tags: apex, soql, visual-workflow

I am working on something I thought would be pretty easy. My Idea was to calculate the win rate of the opportunity owner and display it in a field on the opportunity record. My first thought was an auto-launched flow would be pretty an easy way to look up all opportunities with the same owner ID.  But it is throwing an error.

I then tried to test this with a SOQL query

```
SELECT ID, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = "placeholderforID";
```

The query will not work either.

When I looked at the Owner Object in the workbench it showed a relationship with Opportunity but no child relationship name.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The querry should work given that AddOwnerId is valid userId for that org, do you have opportunity teams enabled

Comment: No we do not.  I never thought that would be the issue.

Comment: Can you try providing a valid ownerID aka userID and see if it works?

Comment: If AddOwnerId is a variable, you need an Apex bind with :AddOwnerId.

Comment: I did the query with my user ID and others from the Dev Console and the workbench and got an error.

Comment: The add owner id was not a variable just a placeholder. I tried to edit above to make that more clear.

Comment: What error are you receiving, Brooks?

Comment: Here is one from the Workbench MALFORMED_QUERY: 
FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = "00550000007eJkBAAU"
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:52
line 1:52 no viable alternative at character '"'

Comment: are you seeing malformed query error? single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: That was embarassing. I have never done a query on an individual ID and did not realize they needed to be in quotes. I thought only a string did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

single quotes, not double quotes. Try:

SELECT ID, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = 'placeholderforID'